# Programmatically reset Windows XP IDLE time

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, qt4

Windows resets the IDLE time every time the user touches the keyboard or the mouse. My application needs to reset the IDLE time at specific moments, but i can't figure out how to do this programmatically.

The following does NOT reset the IDLE time using VB, C# or QT4.
- Programmatic mouse movement / click.
- Programmatic keystroke.
Somehow Windows knows these actions are simulated.

How can i reset the IDLE time? Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to reset the idle time?

Comment: Already tried the [drinking bird technique](http://www.goozex.com/community/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/7/1007.drinking_5F00_bird.jpg)?

Comment: Have you tried [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SetThreadExecutionState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED option (2) resets the system idle timer.  Visit pinvoke.net for the required declarations.

Comment: I think this more specifically answers the question than Anders' does.

Comment: @Earlz: Well, he did not specify _why_ he wanted to reset and which idle timer (system or display) A cd/dvd burner program for example would use ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED while a power point like program would specify ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the display to stay on for example, you would call [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED|ES_CONTINUOUS);

On 2000/XP you could use the ES_USER_PRESENT flag (Does not work on Vista+)

To disable the screen saver, you can handle WM_SYSCOMMAND's SC_SCREENSAVE (You must be the foreground window, otherwise use SystemParametersInfo)

Answer (score 1):

In principle SetThreadExecutionState() should do what you need. But I have found it not to work with the system required flag in some situations on some modern Windows. Sorry, I can't remember exact details.

As a fallback you can just fake some input by calling SendInput() with a null mouse move message for example. My guess is that your input faking failed because you called SendMessage or PostMessage.